# Spring OSGi - unable to autowire the class from external OSGi jar in WAB bundle

Tags: spring, websphere-liberty, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi, spring-dm

I am developing an application using Spring OSGi and IBM WebSphere liberty. I have one WAB bundle which has all controller classes and have another bundle which has all utility/service/dto/model classes.

I loaded the utility bundle to a shared repository and I am trying to autowire the class from the share repo bundle. The problem I am facing is, I am unable to autowire the class (Class is annotated with @Service) from external OSGi jar to WAB bundle. I am getting an exception during the autowire process, which says:

> **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [x.y.z.CodeExternalAutowire] found for dependency [x.y.z.CodeExternalAutowire]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}**

I have verified that the external OSGi jar bundle and package are loaded but am unable to autowire the package class from the WAB. Appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Where is `x.y.z.CodeExternalAutowire` defined? This looks like a classloading problem.

Comment: the class is in another bundle and that bundle is stored in bundle repository. For example, Bundle-A is a web application bundle and Bundle - B is a jar file which has the x.y.z.CodeExternalAutowire class. And, i stored Bundle-B in bundle repository.Here Bundle-A is trying to autowire the Bundle-B classes.

Comment: is Bundle-A importing `x.y.z` package? Can you inspect manifest headers?

Comment: Yes, Bundle-A is imported the package x.y.z with version.